# Add / merge / mutate values to column based on ranges of values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two dataframes, one (called "trialTS") which contains a series of "trials" (1,2,3, etc) and a start and an end timestamp:

```
trial start    end

1   48.37500    49.76822
2   53.90189    55.35198
3   59.48472    60.96783
4   65.10088    66.40155
5   70.55197    71.95272
6   76.08391    77.50065
7   81.63425    83.10151
8   87.23389    88.58481
9   92.71907    93.98458
10  98.11758    99.43337
```

I have a second dataframe (called "eyeData") that contains many rows (>1 million) that have timestamps for sample recordings (from a eyetracker):

```
time      gaze_x    gaze_y
48.37877    -260.5  20.099976
48.37879    -257.8  17.700012
48.37879    -265.5  16.500000
48.37880    -256.6  15.799988
48.37881    -264.1  16.900024
48.37881    -254.5  14.400024
48.37882    -263.0  19.400024
48.37882    -262.6  12.900024
48.38070    -259.4  16.500000
48.38071    -262.5  16.299988
48.38277    -260.8  16.400024
48.38277    -259.3  14.700012
48.38759    -265.9  11.700012
```

I want to be able to add the appropriate trial number to the eyeData recordings. So I need to evaluate each time in eyeData against the start and end columns of trialTS. Here's the current solution:

```
# function to list the trial numbers for the samples
getTrialNumbers <- function(dataIn){
  trialTS %>% 
    filter((dataIn >= trialTS$start) & (dataIn < trialTS$end)) %>% 
    select(trial) %>% 
    as.numeric() %>% 
    return()
}

eyeTrialNums <- flatten_dbl(map(eyeData$time,getTrialNumbers)) # RUNNING THIS TAKES AGES!

cbind(eyeData,eyeTrialNums)
```

The trouble is that the process of doing this over the > 1 million rows of the eyeData dataframe mean that it can take approximately 20 minutes. Can anyone help me with a better solution to this problem?

**data**

```
trialTS <- read.table(h=T,text="trial start    end
1   48.37500    49.76822
2   53.90189    55.35198
3   59.48472    60.96783
4   65.10088    66.40155
5   70.55197    71.95272
6   76.08391    77.50065
7   81.63425    83.10151
8   87.23389    88.58481
9   92.71907    93.98458
10  98.11758    99.43337")

eyeData <- read.table(h=T,text="
  time      gaze_x    gaze_y
48.37877    -260.5  20.099976
48.37879    -257.8  17.700012
48.37879    -265.5  16.500000
48.37880    -256.6  15.799988
48.37881    -264.1  16.900024
48.37881    -254.5  14.400024
48.37882    -263.0  19.400024
48.37882    -262.6  12.900024
48.38070    -259.4  16.500000
48.38071    -262.5  16.299988
48.38277    -260.8  16.400024
48.38277    -259.3  14.700012
48.38759    -265.9  11.700012")
```

Comment: Try with a `non_equi` join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the package *fuzzyjoin* :

```r
fuzzyjoin::interval_right_join(trialTS, eyeData, by = c(start = "time", end = "time"))
#>    trial  start      end     time gaze_x   gaze_y
#> 1      1 48.375 49.76822 48.37877 -260.5 20.09998
#> 2      1 48.375 49.76822 48.37879 -257.8 17.70001
#> 3      1 48.375 49.76822 48.37879 -265.5 16.50000
#> 4      1 48.375 49.76822 48.37880 -256.6 15.79999
#> 5      1 48.375 49.76822 48.37881 -264.1 16.90002
#> 6      1 48.375 49.76822 48.37881 -254.5 14.40002
#> 7      1 48.375 49.76822 48.37882 -263.0 19.40002
#> 8      1 48.375 49.76822 48.37882 -262.6 12.90002
#> 9      1 48.375 49.76822 48.38070 -259.4 16.50000
#> 10     1 48.375 49.76822 48.38071 -262.5 16.29999
#> 11     1 48.375 49.76822 48.38277 -260.8 16.40002
#> 12     1 48.375 49.76822 48.38277 -259.3 14.70001
#> 13     1 48.375 49.76822 48.38759 -265.9 11.70001
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It wraps the package `IRanges` which is designed to work efficiently with ranges, so it should be much faster than what you've tried.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work unfortunately. I get the error: Error in .Call2("solve_user_SEW0", start, end, width, PACKAGE = "IRanges") : 
  In range 193: at least two out of 'start', 'end', and 'width', must
  be supplied.

Comment: strange, with the same data of this example ? copied from what I inserted at the end of your question ?

Comment: I was being really stupid - there were a bunch of NAs in the trialTS dataframe. It works perfectly! thanks very much

Comment: No worries! Better to test on the given example first so we know it s not a version issue. And then indeed it is often missing values :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use a non-equi join from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(eyeData)[trialTS, on = .(time >= start, time < end) , nomatch = FALSE]
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work really well (and is very quick), but it's not quite outputting in the correct manner. Ideally I would want for each row "trial", "time", "start", and "end", plus x and y. See Moody_Muskipper's output below (however I couldn't get that to work).