# Create new column based on whether values in one data frame are within ranges from second data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have an output data frame that contains the predictions of where target sounds are in a set of recordings. The data frame has the sound.file name, start and end time. Here is an example of what my data looks like:

```
preds = pd.DataFrame({
    'sound.file':np.random.choice( ['A','B','C'], 20),
    'start':np.random.choice(10, 20),
    })
preds['end'] = preds['start'] + np.random.choice([1,2], 20)
```

I then have a reference data frame which contains the sound.files names and the actual start and end times of the target signals. The reference detections won't be integers as they are the real timings of calls within the recording.

```
ref = pd.DataFrame({
    'sound.file':np.random.choice( ['A','B','C'], 5),
    'start':np.random.uniform(10, 5),
    })
ref['end'] = ref['start'] + np.random.uniform([1,2], 5)
```

I want to add a column to the `preds` data frame that has either a `1` if a predicted signal overlaps with an actual signal from the same `sound.file` or `0` if it does not.

My output would look something like this:

```
preds['match'] = np.random.choice([0,1], 20)
preds
```

I can do this is `R` and there a a couple of different ways to do it, for example like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308949/add-merge-mutate-values-to-column-based-on-ranges-of-values). However, I am not familiar with python so need some help.

Comment: Hi, is it normal that there are duplicated file names in `ref`? Also, does overlap means *starts or ends between start or end time in ref* and/or *starts before and end after start or end time in ref*?

Comment: Hi @Laurent yes it is normal. This is an example of where I have one dataframe with the actual detections in each file, there may be multiple detections in each file, therefore duplicated file names. It could mean either, all I am looking for is whether there is any kind of overlap, full or partial between the detections in the ```preds``` and ```ref```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### ANSWER TO YOUR POST

With the following random dataframes that I got running your code:
`preds`:

[image]

`ref`:

[image]

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Add interval as a column (e.g. start=1 and end=4 => actual={1, 2, 3, 4}) and groupby
ref["actual"] = ref.apply(lambda x: set(range(x["start"], x["end"] + 1)), axis=1)
ref = ref.groupby("sound.file").agg({"actual": list}).reset_index()

# Add interval as a column
preds["predicted"] = preds.apply(lambda x: set(range(x["start"], x["end"] + 1)), axis=1)

# Add actual column to preds
preds = pd.merge(left=preds, right=ref, on="sound.file", how="left")

# Deal with NaN values
preds["actual"] = preds["actual"].apply(lambda x: [{}] if x is np.nan else x)

# Check for overlaps
preds["match"] = preds.apply(
    lambda x: 1
    if any([x["predicted"].intersection(actual) for actual in x["actual"]])
    else 0,
    axis=1,
)

# Cleanup
preds = preds.drop(columns=["predicted", "actual"])
```

So that `preds`:

[image]

##### BEYOND THE SCOPE OF YOUR POST

Here is how to deal with continuous intervals (float values).

```py
# Setup

preds = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "sound.file": np.random.choice(["A", "B", "C"], 20),
        "start": np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=20),
    }
)
preds["end"] = preds["start"] + np.random.choice([1, 2], 20)
```

`preds`:

[image]

```py
ref = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "sound.file": np.random.choice(["A", "B", "C"], 5),
        "start": np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=5),
    }
)
ref["end"] = ref["start"] + np.random.choice([1, 2], 5)
```

`ref`:

[image]

```py
# Add interval as a column (e.g. start=1.2358 and end=4.4987 => actual=[1.2358, 4.4987]
# and groupby
ref["actual"] = ref[["start", "end"]].apply(lambda x: round(x, 4)).values.tolist()
ref = ref.groupby("sound.file").agg({"actual": sorted}).reset_index()

# Add actual column to preds
preds = pd.merge(left=preds, right=ref, on="sound.file", how="left")

# Deal with NaN values
preds["actual"] = preds["actual"].apply(lambda x: [[-1]] if x is np.nan else x)

# Check for overlaps
preds["match"] = preds.apply(
    lambda x: 1
    if any(
        [(x["start"] >= period[0]) & (x["end"] <= period[-1]) for period in x["actual"]]
    )
    | any(
        [
            (x["start"] >= period[0]) & (x["start"] <= period[-1])
            for period in x["actual"]
        ]
    )
    | any(
        [(x["end"] >= period[0]) & (x["end"] <= period[-1]) for period in x["actual"]]
    )
    | any(
        [(x["start"] <= period[0]) & (x["end"] >= period[-1]) for period in x["actual"]]
    )
    else 0,
    axis=1,
)

# Cleanup
preds = preds.drop(columns="actual")
```

So that `preds`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. Would this also work if the start and ends are ```float``` and not ```int```?

Comment: Then I apologise as it doesn't answer my question, as detections may be decimals. I will edit my questions to more accurately represent my needs.

Comment: Right. I've extended my answer to deal with your actual requirements, as I understand them. Cheers.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I have accepted and upvoted. Really appreciate the time you've spent. Cheers